# PivotViewer not showing images if too many pivotviewer properties

Tags: pivotviewer

I'm updating a pivot viewer application and have run into the following issue. Hopefully someone will have an answer as I'm stuck.

The issue: When the page is loaded the side with properties and other features load fine, but the trading cards don't load any images. Some of them load the default white background while the majority show a dark grey, almost black background. All of them can be zoomed into and show all the properties, but no images.

Debugging: I've discovered that commenting out some of the properties causes the images to load correctly every time. If I comment out only 1 or 2 then the images will load some of the time (about 2 out of 10 page refreshes). Currently there are 29 properties contained in a list and the data is being loaded from a database and then used in the pivotviewer.ItemsSource.

Any ideas?

Code with some name changes (the option two one is the one with the properties I'm commenting out):

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

       PivotViewModel pivotModel = new PivotViewModel();
       CollectionsComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
       this.DataContext = pivotModel;
    }

    private void DropDown_ItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Process selected index change here
        if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedValue == "Option One")
        {
            OptionOnePivotViewModel OptionOnePivot = new OptionOnePivotViewModel();
            PivotViewer.ItemsSource = OptionOnePivot.Data;
            PivotViewer.PivotProperties = OptionOnePivot.PivotProperties;
            PivotViewer.ItemTemplates = OptionOnePivot.TemplateCollection;
            PivotViewer.ItemAdornerStyle = blankAdorner;  
        }
        else
        {
            OptionTwoPivotViewModel OptionTwoPivot = new OptionTwoPivotViewModel();
            PivotViewer.ItemsSource = OptionTwoPivot.Data;
            PivotViewer.PivotProperties = OptionTwoPivot.PivotProperties;
            PivotViewer.ItemAdornerStyle = basicAdorner;
            PivotViewer.ItemTemplates = OptionTwoPivot.TemplateCollection;
        }
    }
```

OptionTwoPivotViewModel.cs:

```
public OptionTwoPivotViewModel()
        {
            DomainContext = new OptionTwoDomainContext();
            Data = DomainContext.Load(DomainContext.GetHRDatasQuery()).Entities;
            PivotProperties = getPivotProperties();
            SmallTemplate = "EmpSmall";

            TemplateCollection = new PivotViewerItemTemplateCollection()
                 {
                 (PivotViewerItemTemplate)  Application.Current.Resources[SmallTemplate]
                 };
        }

        private List<PivotViewerProperty> getPivotProperties()
        {
            List<PivotViewerProperty> properties = new List<PivotViewerProperty>
            {
                new PivotViewerStringProperty{ Id="Name", Options=PivotViewerPropertyOptions.CanSearchText, DisplayName="Name", Binding=new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Name")},
                new PivotViewerStringProperty{ Id="Status", Options=PivotViewerPropertyOptions.CanFilter, DisplayName="Status", Binding=new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Status")},
                new PivotViewerDateTimeProperty{ Id="StartDate", Options=PivotViewerPropertyOptions.CanFilter, DisplayName="Start Date", Binding=new System.Windows.Data.Binding("StartDate")},
                //additional properties follow...
         };
            return properties;
```

Edit: I've noticed that if I set a breakpoint in the following property getter then continue the images also load fine.

```
public ImageSource BackgroundImage
        {
            get
            {
                string location = Image_Location;
                location = location.Substring(location.LastIndexOf("/"));
                Uri uri;

                if (Image_Location.Contains(".gif"))
                {
                    uri = new Uri(Image_Location, UriKind.Absolute);
                }
                else
                {
                    var host = Application.Current.Host.Source.Host;
                    uri = new Uri("https://" + host + "/fileLibrary/employees/images/500"+location, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                }

                // set the image source 
                BitmapImage bmpImg = new BitmapImage(uri);
                _loaded = _backgroundImage != null;
                if (!_loaded)
                {
                    bmpImg.ImageOpened += ImageOpened;
                    bmpImg.ImageFailed += ImageFailed;
                }
                return new BitmapImage(uri);
            }
```

Comment: Could you add your code to the question?

Comment: Added. Let me know if you need additional sections of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
       TemplateCollection = new PivotViewerItemTemplateCollection()
             {
             (PivotViewerItemTemplate)  Application.Current.Resources[SmallTemplate]
             };
```

Not assigning a property in the initializer above?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The initializer shown is just loading the item template. I don't think that has anything to do with the properties. The template looks like: <pv:PivotViewerItemTemplate x:Key="EmpSmall" x:Name="EmpSmall">
        <Grid Width="500" Height="571" Background="White">
            <Image Source="{Binding BackgroundImage}"/>
        </Grid>
    </pv:PivotViewerItemTemplate>